# Problems with shiny::updateDateRangeInput()

Tags: r, shiny

I have a set of data with different date ranges for different locations. I would like my date range widget to update the minimum and maximum dates after selecting a location with the select box widget.

I have tried the steps mentioned in https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#hierarchical-select and have modified it for the date range widget but it does not seem to be working. I have included a reprex below where the start date doesn't seem to update after selecting locations B or C but not A.

```
# Loading up packages required ----

packages <-
  c("data.table", "lubridate", "magrittr", "stringr", "shiny")

invisible(lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE))

rm(packages)

# Dummy data ----

set.seed(5L)

dummy_data <- data.table(
  location = c(rep("A", 10L),
               rep("B", 5L),
               rep("C", 3L)),
  date = c(
    seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 10L, by = 1L, length.out = 10L),
    seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 5L, by = 1L, length.out = 5L),
    seq.Date(Sys.Date() - 3L, by = 1L, length.out = 3L)
  ),
  counts = round(runif(18L) * 10L, digits = 0L)
)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(
      h3('Filtering Criteria'),
      selectInput("location", label = h4('Location'), 
                  choices = c("All", unique(dummy_data$location))),
      dateRangeInput("date_range",
                     label = h4('Date Range (YYYY-MM-DD)'),
                     min = min(dummy_data$date),
                     start = min(dummy_data$date),
                     max = max(dummy_data$date),
                     end = max(dummy_data$date))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h4('Dashboard'),
      tableOutput("data")
    )

  )

)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Filter location
  location_filter <- reactive({
    if (input$location == "All") {
      dummy_data
    } else {
      dummy_data[location == input$location]
    }
  })
  observeEvent(location_filter(), {
    updateDateRangeInput(session,
                         "date_range",
                         min = min(location_filter()$date),
                         start = min(location_filter()$date),
                         end = max(location_filter()$date),
                         max = max(location_filter()$date))
  })

  # Table Output
  output$data <- renderTable({
    location_filter() %>%
      .[date >= input$date_range[1] & date <= input$date_range[2]] %>%
      .[, date := as.character(date)]
  })

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am very new to shiny as I've just picked it up 2-3 weeks ago so please be gentle with me if it's a noob mistake.

Comment: Very nice reprex, by the way.

Comment: Thank you! It's actually exactly the same as the script for the dashboard without a few packages not required for this part and the addition of the dummy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with setting `min`/`start` or `max`/`end` at the same time.  You have to ensure that `start` and `end` both lie within the range [`min` and `max`] at all times.  The easiest way to do this was to split the update into stages:

1. Set `min` and `max` to the earlest and latest dates in the whole
   dataset
2. Set `start` and `min` to earliest and latest dates at the
   current location
3. Set `min` and `max` to the earliest and latest
   dates at the current location

I combined 1 and 2 in a single call to `updateDateRangeInput`.

It's messy, but it seems to work.

I changed the structure of your reactives slightly whilst investigating whether there was priority issue with their updates.  Here's the whole server function.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  locationData <- reactive({
    if (input$location == "All") {
      dummy_data
    } else {
      dummy_data[location == input$location]
    }

  })

  filteredData <- reactive({
    locationData() %>%
      .[date >= input$date_range[1] & date <= input$date_range[2]] %>%
      .[, date := as.character(date)]
  })

  # Filter location
  observeEvent(input$location, {
    updateDateRangeInput(session,
                         "date_range",
                         min = min(dummy_data$date),
                         max = max(dummy_data$date),
                         start = min(locationData()$date),
                         end = max(locationData()$date))
    updateDateRangeInput(session,
                         "date_range",
                         min = min(locationData()$date),
                         max = max(locationData()$date))
  })
  # Table Output
  output$data <- renderTable({
    filteredData()
  })
}
```

I'd be tempted to post this as an issue with Rstudio to see if this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Try to filter `A` twice - your approach returns an empty table.

Comment: Correct.  I only checked that I got data for A, B and C first time around.  I didn't go further than that.  Apologies.  But at least it worked first time round, so that's a small improvement... :)

Comment: Updated solution in line with @ismirsehregal 's observation.

Comment: I'd also encourage you to create an issue on GitHub. It's strange behaviour.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick replies and the suggestions!
Issue has been submitted (https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2915)