# updateSelectInput() in renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

somehow the `updateSelectInput()` is not shown in `renderUI()` which is shown after picking a particular choice from another `selectInput()`.

Rexp for this problem:

UI-logic:

```
selectInput("selectedA", "Choose", choices = c("do not trigger", "Triggerstring")),
uiOutput("dependent_select"),
```

Serverlogic:

```
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "selectedB", choices = select_list())
  })

  select_list <- reactive({
    req(df())
    df_0 <- df()
    list <- apply(combn(unique(df_0$SampleType),2),2,paste, collapse="-")
    return(list)
  })

  output$dependent_select <- renderUI({
    req(input$selectedA == "Triggerstring")
    selectInput("selectedB", "choose B", "")
  })
```

In a non dependent `selectInput()` this method works just fine.

BR
Lukas

Edit: Example dataframe added:

```
df <- reactive({
data.frame(c("Sample_A","Sample_B","Sample_C"), c(1,2,3))
colnames(df) <- c("SampleType", "Value")
)}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, what is your data frame here

Comment: Thanks for your help. Added example dataframe accordingly.

Comment: `updateSelectInput` updates an existing widget.  It does not create a new one.  You need to create the widget somewhere else, and then update it in an `observeEvent()` or similar.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171194/problems-with-shinyupdatedaterangeinput) for a similar question related to `dateRangeInput`s.  The solution transfers here immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Limey:"See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171194/problems-with-shinyupdatedaterangeinput) post for a similar question related to dateRangeInputs. The solution transfers here immediately."

I needed to change the `observe()` function to `observeEvent()` and add the trigger for calculating the `select_list()` reactive variable in this case.

In my case this was another `selectInput("user_selection", "please choose", choices=c("A", "B"))` which can be accessed via `input$user_selection`.

This forces the application to update the `select_list()` reactive variable.